# Failed to start the application on WinCE

Tags: .net

I installed a program on `Windows CE`, it worked for 3-4 months.

Then the battery on the device has stopped charging a couple of days have been able to charge the device, but now when you start the application issued such an error:
[image]

What to do?

Comment: Is this *your* program, or is this a *third-party* software? If the latter, then this is the wrong place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The message is self-explanatory: Your application requires a newer version of .Net Compact  Framework. This means you need to install required compact framework on device before executing application.

Here is what happened to your device:
When main battery died files and applications in device which are not a part of initial software provided by manufacturer have been deleted. When you recharge the battery and boot, only initial packages are installed. In your case manufacturer have included a .Net Compact Framework in ROM which is older than what you need.

If you install .Net Compact Framework 3.5 on device your problem will be solved.